# How can I rotate images to face the mouse cursor

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse

I have a bunch of images scattered around the hero section and I want them all to rotate to face the mouse cursor.

[image: This is how the scene looks like. (still in progress)]

This is my current code:

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body{
    margin: 0;
}

.hero{
    background-image: linear-gradient(to right, #222125 7px, transparent 1px),
                      linear-gradient(to bottom, #222125 7px, transparent 1px);
    background-size: 20vw 20vw; /* Adjust grid size */
    background-color: #242529;
    height: 100vh;

    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
}

.human{
    position: absolute;
    width: 8.6%;
    bottom: -20vh;
}
.guns{
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.gun{
    position: absolute;
    border: 2px solid red;
}

#gun1{
    right: 30%;
    bottom: 30%;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
    scale: -1 1;
}
#gun2{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun3{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun4{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun5{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun6{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun7{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun8{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun9{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun10{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun11{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun12{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun13{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun14{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun15{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun16{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun17{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun18{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun19{
    right: 27%;
    top: 40%;

    width: 9.5vw;
    rotate: 330deg;
}
#gun20{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun21{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun22{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun23{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun24{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun25{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun26{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
#gun27{
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;

    width: 5vw;
    rotate: 0deg;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="hero">
        <img src="assets/human.png" class="human">

        <div class="guns">
            <img src="assets/guns/9mm.png" class="gun" id="gun1">
            <img src="assets/guns/120 cannon.png" class="gun" id="gun2">
            <img src="assets/guns/crystal gun.png" class="gun" id="gun3">
            <img src="assets/guns/dissassembler.png" class="gun" id="gun4">
            <img src="assets/guns/flamethrower.png" class="gun" id="gun5">
            <img src="assets/guns/flintlock.png" class="gun" id="gun6">
            <img src="assets/guns/freezeray.png" class="gun" id="gun7">
            <img src="assets/guns/g1 smg.png" class="gun" id="gun8">
            <img src="assets/guns/grenade launcher.png" class="gun" id="gun9">
            <img src="assets/guns/Handcannon.png" class="gun" id="gun10">
            <img src="assets/guns/heatray.png" class="gun" id="gun11">
            <img src="assets/guns/ion cannon.png" class="gun" id="gun12">
            <img src="assets/guns/lmg.png" class="gun" id="gun13">
            <img src="assets/guns/machine blaster.png" class="gun" id="gun14">
            <img src="assets/guns/minigun.png" class="gun" id="gun15">
            <img src="assets/guns/missile launcher.png" class="gun" id="gun16">
            <img src="assets/guns/pistol.png" class="gun" id="gun17">
            <img src="assets/guns/pulse drum.png" class="gun" id="gun18">
            <img src="assets/guns/revolver.png" class="gun" id="gun19">
            <img src="assets/guns/rigidifier.png" class="gun" id="gun20">
            <img src="assets/guns/rpg.png" class="gun" id="gun21">
            <img src="assets/guns/shotgun.png" class="gun" id="gun22">
            <img src="assets/guns/smg.png" class="gun" id="gun23">
            <img src="assets/guns/soviet smg.png" class="gun" id="gun24">
            <img src="assets/guns/spike rifle.png" class="gun" id="gun25">
            <img src="assets/guns/stormban.png" class="gun" id="gun26">
            <img src="assets/guns/stunner.png" class="gun" id="gun27">
        </div>
    </section>

    <script src="guns.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

each individual gun has the class name "gun" and the id "gun1, gun2, gun3, etc.."

I have tried other people's code but couldn't implement it properly and chatgpt gave me code that somewhat works but only at certain positions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is `gun.js`?

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius its the javascript file

Comment: Yes, I appreciate that it is a JavaScript file - the `.js` at the end gives that away. I had hoped that you **might** have understood and included the actual contents of it that you have so far because currently all you have is some basic CSS and basic HTML.  If you have got code that "sort of works" - please add it to your question rather than expect others to completely write a bespoke solution for you

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius ahh alright

Answer (score 0):

I create an example that you can test it,hope its helpfull

```html
<style>
  .gun {
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
    position: fixed;
    left: 500px;
    top: 500px;
    display: flex;
  }
</style>
<div class="gun">
  <div style="width: 100px;height: 20px;background-color: red;"></div>
  <div style="width: 50px;height: 50px;background-color: red;">gan</div>
</div>
<script>
  window.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
    const {
      clientX,
      clientY
    } = e
    const x = clientX - 500
    const y = clientY - 500
    let deg = Math.atan(y /x) * (180 / Math.PI)
    if (x > 0 && y < 0) deg = 90
    if (x > 0 && y > 0) deg = -90
    const gun = document.querySelector('.gun')
    gun.style.transform = `rotate(${deg}deg)`
  })
</script>
```

Comment: Didnt work, it only moves one gun and every gun should be in a random position on the screen so i want the code to work on every gun no matter its location. thanks anyways